# How to call extension method without passing type parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, type-inference

I have the following types:

```
    public abstract class Game<TRules>
        where TRules : new()
    {
        public TRules Rules { get; set; } = new TRules();
    }

    public class Cricket : Game<CricketRules>
    {
    }

    public class CricketRules
    {
        public string SomeRule { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have an extension method that helps set the rules property:

```
    public static class GameExtensions
    {
        public static void SetRules<TGame, TRules>(this TGame game, Action<TRules> setter)
            where TGame : Game<TRules>
            where TRules : new()
        {
            setter(game.Rules);
        }
    }
```

and I'm able to call the extension method:

```
    new Cricket().SetRules<Cricket, CricketRules>(r => { r.SomeRule = "rule"; });
```

but I get an error when I omit specifying the type parameters:

```
    new Cricket().SetRules(r => { r.SomeRule = "rule"; }); // doesn't compile
```

I'd have expected the extension method to infer both `TGame` as `Cricket` and `TRules` as `CricketRules` in this case due to the constraint `TGame : Game<TRules>` on the method.

Is there any way to avoid passing the type parameters explicitly when calling the extension method?

**Note**: I've seen some SO answers that suggest (for slightly different scenarios) splitting the extension method into two (in different classes) each taking a single type parameter but am not able to figure out a similar approach that would work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the type in the lambda:

```
new Cricket().SetRules((CricketRules r) => { r.SomeRule = "rule"; });
```

Normally (or rather, almost always) you'd omit the type name. People omit it so often that people forget that you *can* put the type name there... :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to avoid passing in the type parameters entirely and have them inferred. The `TRule` type names are expected to be very long, which is why I'm trying to provide an extension method instead of setting the rules like `cricket.Rules = new LongRulesName {...}` each time.

Comment: @Khan I thought you didn’t like passing `TGame`... but how can `TRule` be inferred? I, as a human, can’t even infer it! :)

Comment: @Khan oh I see! So you want to “associate” 2 types: `Cricket` with `CricketRules`. Is that right?

Comment: I'd thought it would infer from the `TGame : Game<TRules>` constraint on the extension method. So when I call the method on an object of type `Cricket<CricketRules>`, I was expecting it to also infer `TRules` as `CricketRules`. It's probably not supported by C# I think but perhaps there are other workarounds for this like splitting into two extension methods taking a single type parameter each?

Comment: Just saw your latest comment, yes that's what I'm after

Comment: @Khan C#'s generics are unfortunately not powerful enough. You need something like the "associated types" feature in Swift to do this. So if you really don't like the `TRule` parameter, you need to redesign your classes...